# Codename One - Simple request to a RESTfull server

Tags: codenameone

I tested with Postman that my Spring Boot RESTfull API works correctly if I send a PUT request to `http://localhost:8080/app` with the header `Content-Type = application/json` and the body `{"appName": "Fake app (for testing)"}`. The response from this call is a simple random string and the status is "200 OK". I tried to replicate the same request with Codename One without success, I get a Dialog error with the text `400: null`. What's wrong in the following code?

```
public static void registerApp() {
        ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();
        request.setContentType("application/json");
        request.setUrl("http://localhost:8080/app");
        request.setHttpMethod("PUT");

        String appName = Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppName", "");

        request.addArgument("appName", appName);

        request.addResponseListener((e) -> {
            Log.p("App registered");
        });

        // request will be handled asynchronously
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(request);
}
```

I also need to do some operations on the random string returned by the server (on success), but I don't know how to get that string.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addArgument` uses standard HTTP arguments used in form submission not JSON arguments so what you are getting (which you can see in the network monitor tool) is `appName=appName` within the body.

You could use:

```
request.setRequestBody("{\"appName\": \"Fake app (for testing)\"}");
```

Or more simply:

```
request.setRequestBody("{'appName': 'Fake app (for testing)'}");
```

Personally, I've been gravitating towards the newer `Rest` API which you can use like this:

```
Response<String> result = 
    Rest.put(url).
    jsonContent().
    body("{'appName': 'Fake app (for testing)'}").getAsString();
```

See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/terse-rest-api.html

Comment: Thank you, I solved with the Rest class as you suggested. Please note that I cannot use the single quotes like in `"{'appName':` because I get the error: `{"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException","message":"JSON parse error: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): was expecting double-quote to start field name}`